# Openstack Cinder LVM configuration

Tags: lvm, openstack, cinder

I'm installing block storage node in my OpenStack infrastructure and couldn't understand how to properly configure filters in lvm.conf. I'm installing Ocata release using this [guide](https://docs.openstack.org/ocata/install-guide-ubuntu/cinder-storage-install.html), the LVM config part is quite confusing. As far as I understood I should filter certain physical volumes to avoid LVM scanning both on host and guest OS.

Lets say I have following PV-s: **/dev/md2p1** for OS, and **/dev/md2p2** for cinder. How should I:

1. Configure filters in lvm.conf on host OS?
2. Configure filters in lvm.conf on guest OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter should be in the host system. The guest system could be any OS. Some of them that doesn't even use LVM.

You need to filter out any partition or logical volume that it is used directly as a virtual disk. The reason is that those block devices could contain a LVM disk label created by the guest OS which should not be used by the LVM running on the host.

Please also note that activating LVM PV on 2 machines without being in a clustered LVM it is unsafe. Also mounting the same file system in the guest and host at the same time will lead to data corruption. There are [some filesystems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustered_file_system#SHARED-DISK) that can be mounted by 2 or more machines at the same time like `gfs2` and `lustre`, but those are not very popular. Filtering out those volumes will avoid these 2 problems.